# How to draw a path or line between three coordinates in android google map view?

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding

How can I draw a line between three geo points (coordinates) in android google map view? Most of the examples show between two geo points.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override the Overlay to define your customized draw with your points (whether you have 2 or three points, you can control your draw logic by yourself)